# How to send input to a website from a LINUX script

Tags: linux, shell, curl, sh, ksh

I have a shell script that takes input from the user, I need to feed that input to a website.  For example

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Enter Your name > "
read name
echo -n "Enter Your age > "
read age
echo -n "Enter your marks > "
read marks
# now all these 3 inputs have to be feed automatically to a website  (e.g.abc.mydomain.com) which has the data field to take the input.
```

Comment: Define "feed ... to a website".

Comment: Combining echo and read can be done with `read -p "Enter your name > " name`.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the data to json format and then use curl to send post request to the website Url with the data.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Enter Your name > "
read name
echo -n "Enter Your age > "
read age
echo -n "Enter your marks > "
read marks

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"name\" : \"$name\", \"age\" : \"$age\", \"marks\" : \"$marks\"}" http://abc.mydomain.com
```